# ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I tried to run a word count spark app every time I get this error please help, following is the `wordcount.scala` file and after `sbt` package I ran the `spark-submit` command

```
package main

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Word Count")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val textfile = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/README.md")
    val tokenizeddata = textfile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    val countprep = tokenizeddata.map(word => (word,1))
    val counts = countprep.reduceByKey((accumvalue,newvalue)=>(accumvalue+newvalue))
    val sortedcount = counts.sortBy(kvpair=>kvpair._2,false)
    sortedcount.saveAsTextFile("file:///usr/local/wordcount")
  }
}
```

I ran the next command.

```
 bin/spark-submit --class "main.WordCount" --master "local[*]" "/home/hadoop/SparkApps/target/scala-2.10/word-count_2.10-1.0.jar"
```

> Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on
>   classpath    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning:
>
> ### ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0    15/11/28 07:38:51 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 1.0
>
> (TID 1)    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>                   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>                   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>                   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>                   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>                   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>                   at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
>                   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
>                   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
>                   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211)
>                   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
>                   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
>                   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
>                   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
>                   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
>                   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
>                   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:375)
>                   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$6.apply(Executor.scala:325)
>                   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$6.apply(Executor.scala:323)
>                   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
>                   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
>                   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
>                   at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
>                   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
>                   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
>                   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
>                   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:323)
>                   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:158)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I think you need set spark home in your application

Comment: Can you share the entire output from `spark-shell`? You should see `INFO SparkContext: Added JAR` message in-between. I wonder if the stable version `1.0` makes itself troublesome for Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add .setMaster("local")